# What is the difference between "Make" and "Get" when they come with an adjective?

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

I see that people use both of them, but are there any differences between them? what do they mean exactly?

For instance:

> I got him upset.

> I made him upset.

Answer (score 1):

Both *make* and *get* participate in galore idioms, so they certainly can't be swapped. In cases where they both work, they mostly mean the same (`Cause`), but any differences that aren't idiomatic have to do with the equation of *make* with *create*, a permanent and serious effect, which allows *get* to refer preferentially to temporary and frivolous effects (*Get him to bend over, Get him drunk, Get it working*).

Comment: As I put it originally, "I said what I think in a comment. But I can't read it when they're locked." I would probly format this differently, but it's what I'd put in an answer.

Comment: Another distinction between _make_ and _get_ with adjectives is that _get_, but not _make_, can be inchoative and not just causative. You can get him tired, or you can get tired. You can make him tired, but you can't *make tired. _Make_ is strictly causative (and transitive); _get_ can swing both ways.

Comment: What's a galore idiom?

Comment: _Galore_ is plural, and famous as a quantifier that can't precede its noun. _Beautiful women galore_, but not *_galore beautiful women_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you expound on how "get" refers preferentially to "temporary and frivolous" effects?

"Get him to…" isn't quite "Make him bend over…" and "Get it working…" isn't quite "Make it work…" but how is "Get him…" different at all from "Make him drunk…", how are any of those differences "temporary and frivolous" and come to that, how are "temporary" and "frivolous" comparable?

Comment: "Made him drunk" used to be used, certainly in the English north east. The Napoleonic era folk song "The recruited collier" contains the lines **"And them red-coated fellows / Enticed him in, and _made him drunk_, and he'd better gone to the gallows'**.

Comment: @Rosie F; A galore idiom is like an ostentation of peafowl or a murder of crows. Just how many idiom is the question.